# Object Expected Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, object

I am using JS-Graph.IT to create a flowchart diagram and want to upon selection of a dropdown option, load a div with an altered version of the flowchart. Prior to loading AJAX content, the flow diagram works and shows boxes with arrows pointing from one box to another. After loading AJAX content, the connectors can't seem to be generated.

I found here that it is because of the need to clear the canvas before using the same canvas ids. [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/js-graph-it/discussion/582281/thread/4ebe3ae5/) I tried following the instructions and copied the delCanvas function to the JS file, and calling the delCanvas function and reinitializing page objects in the header of the HTML page as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    JSGraphIt.initPageObjects();

    $("body").delegate("#button1", "click", function() {
        delCanvas('#mainCanvas');

        var button2 = $('#combo').val();
        $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
            url: 'serverside17.php', // JQuery loads serverside.php
            data: 'button2=' + $('#combo').val(), // Send value of the clicked button
            dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
            success: function(data) // Variable data constains the data we get from serverside
            {
                JSGraphIt.initPageObjects();
                $('#mainCanvas').html(''); // Clear #content div
                $('#mainCanvas').append(data);
            }
        });
    });

});

</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

HTML page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title></title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> <!-- Jquery for Slide Toggle -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js-graph-it.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../sf-homepage.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0; 
        overflow:hidden;
    }
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onLoad()
{
    JSGraphIt.initPageObjects();
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".block").bind('click', $.proxy(function(event) {
        var input = $(event.target).attr('id');
        var lines = input.split('_');
        var button = lines[0];
        $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
            url: 'srvrside.php', // JQuery loads serverside.php
            data: 'button=' + button, // Send value of the clicked button
            dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
            success: function(data) // Variable data constains the data we get from serverside
            {
                $('#content').html(''); // Clear #content div
                $('#content').append(data);
            }
        });
        return false; // keeps the page from not refreshing 

    }, this));

    $("#button1").bind('click', $.proxy(function(event) {
        var button2 = $('#combo').val();
        $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
            url: 'serverside15.php', // JQuery loads serverside.php
            data: 'button2=' + $('#combo').val(), // Send value of the clicked button
            dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
            success: function(data) // Variable data constains the data we get from serverside
            {
                $('#mainCanvas').html(''); // Clear #content div
                $('#mainCanvas').append(data);
                JSGraphIt.initPageObjects();
            }
        });
        return false; // keeps the page from not refreshing 

    }, this));

});

</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad();">

    <select id="combo">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <input id="button1" type="button" value="Click!" />

    <div id="mainCanvas" class="canvas" style="float: left; background: #F8F8F8; width: 100%; height: 60%; border-top: #ccc 1px solid !important; border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid !important; margin: 0 !important; border-left: 0; border-right: 0; padding: 0 !important;">

        <?php
            ***database connection details***

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo '<div id="'.$row['id'].'_block" class="block" style="background: red;';
                echo ' !important; left:'.$row['lft'].'px; top:'.$row['top'].'px; width: 100px;">';
                echo '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 8px;">'.$row['level'].'</span> &nbsp;';
                echo $row['name'];
                echo '</div>';
            }   

            // Creating connectors
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM dependencies");

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo '<div class="connector '.$row['app1id'].'_block '.$row['app2id'].'_block ';
                if ($row['down_arrow'] == 1) {
                    echo 'down_start">';
                }
                else {
                    echo 'right_start">';
                }
                echo '<img class="connector-end" src="arrow.gif">';
                echo '<label class="middle-label">'.$row['desc'].'</label>';
                echo '</div>';
            }

            // Closing database connection
            mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Server side PHP:

```
<?php  

// Get value of clicked button 
$button = $_GET['button2'];  

$all = '';

***Database connection***

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $all .= '<div id="'.$row['id'].'_block" class="block" style="border: 3px solid #000; background: red;';
                $all .= 'left:'.$row['lft'].'px; top:'.$row['top'].'px; width: 100px;">';
                $all .= '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 8px;">'.$row['level'].'</span> &nbsp;';
                $all .= $row['name'];
                $all .= '</div>';
            }   

            ***database connection***

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $all .= '<div class="connector '.$row['app1id'].'_block '.$row['app2id'].'_block ';
                if ($row['down_arrow'] == 1) {
                    $all .= 'down_start">';
                }
                else {
                    $all .= 'right_start">';
                }
                $all .= '<img class="connector-end" src="arrow.gif">';
                $all .= '<label class="middle-label">'.$row['desc'].'</label>';
                $all .= '</div>';
            }

            // Closing database connection
            mysqli_close($con);

        print json_encode($all);

?>
```

[JS-Graph.IT JS](http://js-graph-it.sourceforge.net/js-graph-it.js)

Comment: #button1 ajax call on serverside15.php is failing?

Comment: @RobertRozas Hi Robert, the #button1 ajax call works. It returns the divs that it should but not the connectors that connect the divs. Imagine a flow chart originally with an arrow between two boxes, but after the ajax call, only the boxes appear but no arrow.

Comment: So this is the line with problems JSGraphIt.initPageObjects(); , right?

Comment: I can't locate the contructor anywhere, have you tried calling the function directly? : initPageObjects();

Comment: @jamesemanon The constructor should be in http://js-graph-it.sourceforge.net/js-graph-it.js. I didn't paste the whole file because it was too long. I also added the delCanvas function into that file